# How to add constraint on the basis of other column

Tags: sql-server

On my table there are two columns. The first one is name(varchar), the second one is status(number). I want to add a constraint so that name field is unique but unless the value of status is 2. If the status has value 2, then allow duplicate names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting a question, especially when relating to an RDBMS, ideally you should provide Sample and Expected results or behaviour.

From your description, however, it seems like what you're after is a unique filtered index. This should get you on the path you need:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE TestTable([name] varchar(50), [status] int)

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX LiveName_UQ ON TestTable([Name]) WHERE [status] = 1; --Guessed that it would be a 1 instead? Maybe it should be <> 2?
GO

INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('John',1); --works
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('Jane',1); --works
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('John',2); --works
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('John',2); --works
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('Jane',1); --fails
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestTable;

GO
DROP TABLE TestTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

why you are not adding two columns primary key as

CONSTRAINT PK_1 PRIMARY KEY (name,status)

Comment: This is a comment, however, a Primary key on `name` and `status` would mean that 2 people with status 2, with the same name, couldn't exist. That does not seem to be what behaviour the OP is after.

Comment: It is not clear in question that ,,status 2 ,containing name should not be unique.

Comment: @Larnu if status 2, containing row is not unique then for your answer thumbs up else if he wants status 2 be unique then he can use primary key,,,,,,,it will solve the problem